# Can't add omouseover attribute dynamically from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, attr, onmouseover

I'm trying to add the attributes dynamically to an img tag but only onmouseenter is not been included else everything is been added perfectly

```
let img_elem = document.createElement('img')
                img_elem.src = movies[i].large_cover_image
                img_elem.alt = 'poster'
                img_elem.id = i
                img_elem.className ='poster'
                img_elem.onmouseover = 'give_me_id(this)'
```

This is my HTML after adding attributes dynamically

```
<img src="https://yts.mx/assets/images/movies/woodstock_99_peace_love_and_rage_2021/large-cover.jpg" alt="poster" id="0" class="poster">
```

Just an issue with onmouseover else everything working perfectly.
I have already found  other ways to add onmouseover attribute but the above method seems to be easier than I have used, so let me know the issue here. Thank you in advance

Comment: It's event and you should be adding as event listener

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because we are trying to add the attribute but what we really want is add event listener. Below is the code please try it out

```js
let img_elem = document.createElement('img');
  img_elem.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/User_icon_2.svg'
  img_elem.alt = 'poster';
  img_elem.id = 'img1'; //i;
  img_elem.className ='poster';
  img_elem.addEventListener("mouseover",function(event){console.log('mouseover');});
  document.getElementById('imgParent').appendChild(img_elem);
```

```html
<div id='imgParent'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're following the [W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onmouseover), but the example is adding a method through the attribute. You can't really do that in javascript code. Instead, you send in a function and then use `event.target` to get which image that the user is hovering. I'm taking one more step, and using shorthand properties (I think that's the name) to get target directly by using `{target}`.

Another way is to add an eventlistener instead, like in Bharat's answer.

```js
const imageIds = [100, 200, 400];

for (const id of imageIds) {
  let img_elem = document.createElement('img');

  img_elem.src = `https://picsum.photos/id/${id}/200/200`;
  img_elem.alt = 'poster';
  img_elem.id  = id;
  img_elem.className   = 'poster';
  img_elem.onmouseover = giveMeId;

  document.body.appendChild(img_elem);
}

function giveMeId({target}) {
  console.log('id:', target.id); 
}
```